# Is there a proof for this relationship that $\beta>\gamma$

Tags: abstract-algebra

if $$\gamma=[\alpha_1d_1+\alpha_2d_2+...+\alpha_nd_n]^2$$
$$\beta=\alpha_1d_1^2+\alpha_2d_2^2+...+\alpha_nd_n^2$$
$$\alpha_1+\alpha_2+...+\alpha_n=1$$
Can we prove that always: $$\beta >\gamma$$

Comment: This is not necessarily true. But if $\alpha_i\ge0$, it can be proved that $\beta\ge\gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

[Hölder's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality) says that if $a_k\ge0$,
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_kd_k\right)^2\le\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_kd_k^2\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right)
$$

---

[Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality) says that since $x^2$ is a convex function of $x$, if $a_k\ge0$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_k=1$,
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_kd_k\right)^2\le\sum_{k=1}^na_kd_k^2
$$